# Number of files in a folder, gives different results

Tags: directory

To count number of files in a folder I'm using:

`ls -l | wc -l`

but this gives 1 more than:

`ls | wc -l`

What causes this? Also what do the three numbers represent for

`ls | wc`

Comment: It is important to note that parsing output of `ls` command is generally considered a bad practice in Linux circles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `ls -l` you're not only getting a list of all files in the specified directory, one file per line, but you also get a `total [BLOCKS]` line at the top which displays how many file system blocks all files in this folder occupy in total. More info about this line can be found at [What is that “total” in the very first line after ls -l?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7401704/4464570) on Stack Overflow.

To just get one line per file (and vice versa), you could use `ls -1` instead which does not add extra information.

---

From `wc`'s manpage:

```
Print  newline,  word,  and  byte counts for each FILE
```

So the first number in `wc`'s output is the number of lines, the second one is the number of words ("*A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.*") and the last number is the input size in bytes.

---

You can read the manpages (manual pages) of most commands by typing `man COMMAND` in the terminal, e.g. `man ls` or `man wc`.

Answer (score 4):

See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) about why trying to process (parse) the output of `ls` is risky.

Instead, get the number of links to the directory (see `man stat`), subtract 2 (for the `.` and `..` entries).

```
dir=$PWD
Nfiles=$(( $(stat --printf=%h $dir) - 2 ))
```

Note: this counts files AND directories in `$dir`. Counting the two separately is a different problem.